# Running gcc failed while building go project in windows

Tags: c, gcc, go, build

I tried compiling my project using `go build` and I get this error:

> C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmingwex
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmingw32
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I've read that linking files with gcc is a [problem](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9510) in compiling go projects with Windows. But I have installed gcc in my Windows system but the error persists. I can see the error above references gcc as in a Linux sistem (/usr/lib) so how would the compiler detect my gcc installation?

EDIT:

My `go env`

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=D:\Go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\wildan\AppData\Loc
al\Temp\go-build554990027=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
```

Using go version 1.8

Comment: Add the output of the `go version` and `go env` commands to your question.

Comment: If don't like the compiler you have download, you should consider [Repl.it](repl.it). It's a good online C compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lmingw32 collect2

You are using cygwin to look for mingw libraries. Don't use cygwin; use a mingw gcc compiler. I use [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download).

Comment: now I get an error:  `\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-826517911\go.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized`

Comment: How did you get it working?  I am having the same error for go.o not recognized.  Thanks!

Comment: I am also getting the error "go.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized". Was anybody able to resolve this?